# Proving convergence or divergence using the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum \frac{n!}{n^{300}}$$

What do I compare it to.

Just a warning, if anyone comes in here and just posts a solution to if this converges or not I will downvote it. I am trying to discuss the comparison test, how rigorous it has to be and how to use.

For example can I say that $$\sum \frac{1}{10^n - 6^n} < \sum \frac{1}{2^n}$$ therefor it converges since 2 > 1

To expand I think nearly every problem in my book can be solved with the comparison test which is faster and easier to use.

Comment: Do you mean "prove or disprove?" Because I don't think this converges.

Comment: Whichever, diverge or converge. I will edit.

Comment: @PaulthePirate, I recommend a less hostile tone in your question, and I recommend not being so aggressive with downvotes.

Comment: @vadim123 I feel like I need to be, this is about the fourth time I have asked this.

Comment: So, you feel the need to be hostile when asking people for help?

Comment: I feel the need to be specific. I think most people see a formula and rush to answer it and ignore what the author wanted.

Comment: Looking over your history, Paul, I don't see this particular question asked at all.  Are you deleting and reposting?  That is also not recommended.

Comment: @PaulthePirate There is a difference between being specific and being belligerent. Might be you've crossed the line.

Comment: What lower bounds for $n!$ do you know?

Comment: I don't know what a lower bound is, so none.

Comment: A lower bound of $n!$ is an expression $f(n)$ in $n$ such that  $f(n) \leq n!$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$

Comment: Just kind of dissapointing when I want to learn math and I come here to discuss math and no one wants to. They are more interested in answering a question and earning points I think.

Comment: Have you seen the Ratio test? It's nice to see that someone actually likes to use the Comparison test; but in many cases, such as this one, it's more trouble to apply than needed.

Comment: Yes I know the ratio test but I am trying to learn the limits of the comparison test. I suppose that factorial is one of those?

Comment: No, you can use the Comparison test here. See Jared's answer. (Unrelated to Jared's answer: Actually the Ratio  Test is a comparison test. But the actual comparison used is hidden.)

Comment: @PaulthePirate do you know the power series for the exponential function $e^{x}$ ? I could use it to prove a simple lower bound for $n!$.

Comment: I have not memorized any power series.

Comment: For your $\frac{1}{10^n-6^n}$, it is true that each term is less than $\frac{1}{2^n}$. But probably you would be expected to explain how you know that.

Comment: How would I explain how I know that? 2 < 4

Comment: No, you would need to show $10^n - 6^n \geq 2^n$ which is not the same as $(10 - 6)^n = 4^n \geq 2^n$

Comment: That is quite easy to show though, at the highest value it could ever be it is 4 (even terms) whereas 2 is ALWAYS larger than that.

Answer (score 4):

Since $n!$ grows faster than $n^{300}$, there will be some value $N$ at which we have the inequality $n!>n^{300}$ for all $n>N$.  You can use this inequality in a comparison:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{300}}=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n!}{n^{300}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{300}}>\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n!}{n^{300}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}1$$

See if you can complete the reasoning to show that the original series diverges.

To see that $n!$ grows faster than $n^k$ for any positive integer $k$, notice for $n>k$ we have:

$$\frac{n!}{n^k}=(n-k)!\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-k+2}{n}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{n}$$

Now, choose $n$ big enough so that $2(n-k+1)>n$.  It follows that each of the $k$ fractions above are greater than $1/2$.  This gives us the inequality:

$$\frac{n!}{n^k}>(n-k)!\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$

Remembering that $k$ is fixed (in our case, $k=300$), as we let $n$ grow, eventually the right hand side of the above inequality will be greater than $1$, so that $n!>n^k$.

Comment: But how do I know that it grows faster?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: I've added an explanation concerning the growth of $n!$.

Comment: I don't follow the significance or even the meaning of (n-k)!

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Suppose we choose $n=700$ and $k=300$.  Then $(n-k)!=(700-300)!=400!$.

Comment: But how did you get to that?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Check the limit of the summand first

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{300}}=\infty. $$

Now, since the limit is $\infty$, then series diverges.

**Note:**

> 1) If a series $\sum b_n $ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = 0$, which implies if   $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n \neq 0 $, then the series diverges.

2) You can use the following result to find the above limit

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a $ and $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =0 $.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @PaulthePirate This is sometimes called the nth-term test.  Basically, terms in the sum must "vanish" as $n\to\infty$ if the series is to converge.  This should be the first thing you test in any series problem.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Find the limit of the summand first, if the limit is not zero, then the series diverges. The note is a technique for how to evaluate the limit.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I don't follow, what is the summan?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: If you have a series $\sum b_n$ then we call $b_n$ the summand.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the downvote for?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the limit comparison test.

Comment: @Downvoter: The down vote is misleading the OP!!

Comment: @PaulthePirate: We are not using the comparison test. I am using the following result: " If a series converges, then the limit of summand has to equal $0$". From this result, you can see that if the limit of the summand is not $0$ then the series diverges.

Comment: I think the downvote is *from* the OP, carrying out the threat from his question.

Comment: @vadim123: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @downvoter: The answer is correct and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the comparison test using the following lower bound of $n!$ :
$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} \leq n!,\space n=1,2,3,...$$ 
**Proof:** Let $x >0:$
$$e^{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\geq \frac{x^{n}}{n!},\space n=1,2,3,...$$
Now substitute $x=n$ and you get:
$$e^{n}\geq \frac{n^n}{n!}, \space n=1,2,3,...$$
Now divide by $e^{n}$ and multiply by $n!$ to get the desired result.