# Divergence of the series $2^{-1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:

Since $\mathrm{lim}_{\ n \to \infty} \displaystyle \frac{(1/2)^{1/n}}{2^n} = \mathrm{lim}_{\ n \to \infty} 2^{1/n} = 1 $ by the limit comparison test, since $\sum 2^n$ diverges, it follows that $\sum 2^{-1/n}$ diverges.

Is this a possible solution?

The error above is in the calculation of the limit. It will approach $0$ since the above becomes $\lim \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/n +n}$. Here is the correct solution:
if $\sum x_n$ converges, then $\mathrm{lim}_{n\to \infty} (x_n) =0$. Since $\lim \displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/n} =1$, the series does not converge.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{-1/n}=1\ne0$, so the $n$ term of the series does not approach zero, so...

Comment: The limit of the ratio is not $1$ but $0$. I cannot fathom how you got $1$.

Comment: It was an error in the calculation. I believe I fixed the solution. A little advice though, saying "I cannot fathom how you got 1" is very discouraging to someone learning mathematics.

Comment: Why? This points to the exact location of the problem and asks for your feedback on it, to understand what went wrong and, if necessary, provide explanations. Note that this is still the only answer on the page to your question "Is this a possible solution?". I cannot fathom how one can read it as discouraging.

Comment: Note also that "I see the error here" is a bit mysterious (but maybe this is "discouraging" as well to say so?), since the rest of the post explains another method and does not address the mistake in the method you presented originally. But if you got what went wrong, all is well.

Comment: Yes, I should probably explain the error. Thank you for that. The word "fathom" is a little strong in this context, that is all I was saying. Upon first reading of your comment I interpreted it as "I have no idea how you possibly got this limit wrong" which is clearly not constructive to learning any subject.

Comment: It was definitely my intention to ask for an explanation about how you got led to this mistake (explanation still absent, by the way). This is the most direct approach I know to be in a position to provide a relevant answer (a position that only my comment tries to reach, at present). (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to make the comparison test. Just notice that the limit of the summand is

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{-1/n} = 1 .$$

That tells you that the series diverges. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455144/proving-convergence-or-divergence-using-the-comparison-test).

Comment: I'm not sure how I got the limit I did but I see the solution. I edited my solution above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user23793: You are welcome.