# Series question with logarithms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I want to know how to check the divergence of following sum: 
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}$

I tried to use this result:  $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}=1 \neq 0 $   but I don't know why this result is true.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that the index of summation is $n$ (not $k$), otherwise the sum diverges trivially.  Otherwise, note that (for $n>1$) we have $n^n>n>\log n$.  Hence $n>\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n]{\log n}$.  We take reciprocals to get $$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}$$

Now you can use the comparison test to complete the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the Contraposition of result

> if a series $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0$.

See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455144/proving-convergence-or-divergence-using-the-comparison-test).

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is large, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}\simeq 1-\frac{\log (\log (n))}{n}$$ So, as you already noticed $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}=1$$ and then the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}$$ diverges.

As said in other answers, the summation should probably start at $n=2$ and not $n=0$ ($n=0$ does not make a problem but $n=1$ makes a serious one).

Using some approximations, it could be easy to show that, for $p \gt 1000$, $$\sum_{n=2}^{n=p} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}\simeq p$$